# Sql Sales Report

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a report for sales.  This is what I have so far but I need to break it down into stores.  There is a field in the orders table for storeid.  I would like to return the totals for each store. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

```
select DAY(d.date) as Day, MONTH(d.date) as Month, YEAR(d.date) as year, isnull(t.amnt, 0) as [Total Sales] from (
    SELECT
    sum(o.OrderTotal) amnt,
            DAY(o.OrderDate) as 'Day', 
            YEAR(o.OrderDate) as 'Year', 
        MONTH(o.OrderDate) as 'Month'
            FROM [Orders] o
            where  
    o.OrderDate  > @StartDate + ' 00:00:00' and o.OrderDate  < '' + @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
    group by YEAR(o.OrderDate), Month(o.OrderDate), DAY(o.OrderDate)
) t
right join (
    select dateadd(dd, -number, getdate()) as date
    from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'p' and number < DATEDIFF(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) +1

) d  on year(d.date) = t.[year] and month(d.date) = t.[month] and day(d.date) = t.[day]
order by YEAR(d.date), MONTH(d.date), DAY(d.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add storeId to the `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT` clause.

```
select DAY(d.date) as Day, MONTH(d.date) as Month, YEAR(d.date) as year, isnull(t.amnt, 0) as [Total Sales], o.storeId from (
    SELECT
    sum(o.OrderTotal) amnt,
            DAY(o.OrderDate) as 'Day', 
            YEAR(o.OrderDate) as 'Year', 
        MONTH(o.OrderDate) as 'Month'
            FROM [Orders] o
            where  
    o.OrderDate  > @StartDate + ' 00:00:00' and o.OrderDate  < '' + @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
    group by YEAR(o.OrderDate), Month(o.OrderDate), DAY(o.OrderDate), o.storeId
) t
right join (
    select dateadd(dd, -number, getdate()) as date
    from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'p' and number < DATEDIFF(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) +1

) d  on year(d.date) = t.[year] and month(d.date) = t.[month] and day(d.date) = t.[day]
order by YEAR(d.date), MONTH(d.date), DAY(d.date)
```